# Using a dijit.Menu like a combo box to select a value

Tags: drop-down-menu, dojo, xpages

I get a list of column values from a view that I feed into a comboBox to select a value and store it in a field. From a look and feel I would like to feed this list to dijit.Menu I have not done much with dojo and have not been able to find an example that could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried the examples here? http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Menu.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the drop-down button from ExtLib which would provide a similar look and feel:

```
    <xe:dropDownButton
        id="dropDownButton1">
        <xe:this.treeNodes>
            <xe:basicContainerNode>
                <xe:this.label><![CDATA[#{empty viewScope.myValue?"Select a value...":viewScope.myValue}]]></xe:this.label>
                <xe:this.children>
                    <xe:basicLeafNode
                        label="Label 1"
                        submitValue="value1">
                    </xe:basicLeafNode>
                    <xe:basicLeafNode
                        label="Label 2"
                        submitValue="value2">
                    </xe:basicLeafNode>
                </xe:this.children>
            </xe:basicContainerNode>
        </xe:this.treeNodes>
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onItemClick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial"
            refreshId="dropDownButton1">
            <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var value=context.getSubmittedValue();
if(value!=null && value!="") viewScope.myValue=value;}]]></xe:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xe:dropDownButton>
```

Here, `viewScope.myValue` is the secret data binding. You have to handle the data validation separately (maybe via an inputHidden component). Also you might use `repeatTreeNode` instead of `beanLeafNode`, so you would have calculated list of options.

Comment: that works with the repeatTreeNode. I tried setting the style for the dropDownButton so that it displays a fixed width and change the background color, but the style settings don't appear to have any impact on the button. I disabled the Theme as well and that doesn't appear to do much. Appart from that it is working fine.

Comment: To style the main button, you need to set styleClass for the `basicContainerNode` first. It will set the class for the span wrapping the button. Then you can use `.myContainer button {...}` as the CSS rule.